# Independent events or conditional probability?

Tags: probability

In my daily morning walk there is a 20% chance I drop my pouch.
Every day I follow the exact same straight path, to the district square and then back.
Assuming that my walk is on a straight segment from A to B and then back from B to A, what is the probability I dropped it from A to B?

I know this seems to be a very easy problem, but I am a little confused:
Initially, there is equal probability for me to drop my pouch in any of the two directions.
So for AB, this probability is 50% of 20%?

But for the second part of my walk back home, the probability is conditional.
If I have already dropped it in AB, the probability is zero. If I haven’t, the probability is 100% of the total 20%, that is, 20%.

Any clue?

Edit : There are two answer which have been updated, but they sort of conflict each other. Any help clearing it out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming there's nothing special about going one way or the other, then you can say that the probability you drop your wallet going from A to B is $p$, and the probability that you drop it going from B to A, *conditional* on not dropping it from B to A, is also $p$.

Then the probability that you drop the wallet going from B to A is given by $P(BA) = P(BA \land \lnot AB) = P(BA | \lnot AB)P(\lnot AB) = p(1-p)$, i.e. it's the product of the probabilities of (a) not dropping the wallet going from A to B, and (b) dropping the wallet going from B to A, having not dropped it going from A to B.

So the overall probability you drop your wallet somewhere on the walk is the sum of the two events - $P(AB \lor BA) = P(AB) + P(BA \land \lnot AB) = p + p(1-p) = p(2-p)$.

Then since we know this overall probability, we can say $p(2-p) = 0.2$ and solve for $p$, getting $p = 1 - \frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5} \approx 0.10557$.

Comment: @all: We know that the total chance of losing my pouch is 20%. Since I walk in two equivalent, in terms of distance, risk etc, routes, I think that intuitively there is a slightly increased chance I lose it in the second route, which is also supported by Bayes, as explained by user2661923 ($\frac{1}{9}$ as opposed to $\frac{1}{10}$).

Comment: So, would it be wrong to say that (probability I lost it in the first route) = $\frac{2}{10}$ - $\frac{1}{9}$?

Comment: @EduardoJuanRamirez The probability that the pouch is lost on the first half is $\approx 10.557\%$. The probability that it is lost on the second half is $\approx 9.443\%$ and is smaller than the previous one (and it is *not* $1/9$), because it is really $10.557\%$ of the probability $\approx 1-0.10557$ that it was not lost on the first half. The probability that the pouch is not lost is $80\%$.

Comment: The unconditional probability of dropping it on AB is the same as dropping it on BA based on the info in the question since nothing was given to indicate that BA is any more perilous to the wallet than AB. But the conditional probability of dropping it on BA given you didn't drop it on AB *is* different from the unconditional probability of dropping it on AB (and also that of dropping it on BA).

Comment: Ultimately, all of the answers are making assumptions, and there's no way of knowing which assumption is correct because that all comes down to what's being modelled. I can only argue by way of a somewhat ridiculous analogy - suppose you walk for 100 km, and on each km of your route there's a sniper waiting to shoot you. If you're still alive on the last km, then that sniper has as good a chance of killing you as the other 99 did, but overall they have a smaller chance because as soon as one sniper gets you all of the rest have no opportunity to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Let $E_{1}$ be the event of non-dropping on segment $AB$ and let
$E_{2}$ be the event of non-dropping on segment $BA$.

Then: $$P\left(E_{2}\mid E_{1}\right)=P\left(E_{1}\right)\tag1$$(any objections against $(1)$? Please let me know)

or equivalently:
$$P\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\right)=P\left(E_{1}\right)^{2}$$

This with: $$P\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\right)=1-0.2=0.8$$ so that: $$P\left(E_{1}^{\complement}\right)=1-P\left(E_{1}\right)=1-\sqrt{0.8}\approx0.105573$$

Not an essentially different answer but a bit more concise. It all rests on the concept of a distribution that has no memory.

---

**Edit** (inspired by the answer of @user2661923)

Let us look at the following experiment in order to compare.

There are $10$ marbles in a bag and exactly one of them is red. We pick $2$ marbles one by one without replacement (which is essential here). Analogously let $E_1$ be the event that the first picked marble is not red and let $E_2$ be the event that the second picked marble is not red. Then easily we find that:$$P(E_1)=P(E_2)=0.9\text{ and }P(E_1^{\complement}\cup E_1^{\complement})=P(E_1^{\complement})+P(E_2^{\complement})=0.2$$
Note that in this situation:$$P(E_2\mid E_1)=\frac89\neq0.1=P(E_1)\tag2$$
This because under condition $E_1$ the second pick is from a bag containing $9$ (not $10$) marbles of which exactly one is red. In short: "things have changed". This however is definitely not the case for the walk on segment $BA$ under the condition that there was no dropping during the walk on segment $AB$. Under that condition things are exactly the same as they were by the start of the walk on segment $AB$. That is an essential difference.

I am convinced that in the situation sketched in your question statement $(1)$ is correct and statement $(2)$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

To be added to other already good answers.

It seems that your model corresponds to a failure model with constante rate - that is, the probability of "fail" (dropping your pouch) in the next (small) walking step, given that you have not yet failed, is a constant, only depending on (proportional to)  the length (in time or space) of the step. Let's use space walked, so that the walk goes from $x=0$ to $x=2$, with $x=1$ being the point of return.

Then, the conditional probability of fail in the interval $[x, x+\delta x)$ is $\lambda\, \delta x$ , for small $\delta x$. In the limit this tends to a [exponential distribution](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/apr/section1/apr161.htm).

Then, the probability of fail over some interval $L$ is $P(L)=1- \exp(-\lambda L)$

We know that $P(2)=0.2$, then $\lambda = -\log(0.8)/2 = 0.11157$

Hence, the probability of failing over the first half of the trajectory is $P(1)=1-\exp(-\lambda)= 0.1055729 \approx  10.56\%$

Also, without solving for $\lambda$:

$$P(1)= 1- \exp(-\lambda) = 1 - \sqrt{\exp(- 2 \lambda )}=1-\sqrt{1+P(2)}$$

which gives the same result and agrees with @ConMan.

Notice that this $P(1)$ is the probability of dropping the pouch in the first part ($A\to B$), and also the probability of dropping it in the second part ($B \to A$)  given that it was not dropped before.

The relationship above shows that $P(1) \ne \frac{1}{2} P(2)$ (but this is asympotically right if the probability is small).

Answer (score 2):

+1 : also - nicely questioned.

Depends on what simplifying assumptions that you make.

As you have surmised, the following events are mutually exclusive:

- dropping the pouch when going from A to B
- dropping the pouch when going from B to A

Therefore, the two events can not be regarded as independent.

Further, absent any other information, it is reasonable to assume that there is a $10\%$ chance of dropping the pouch when going from A to B and a $10% chance of dropping the pouch when going from B to A.

What is confusing you is that the events are not being **trialed** simultaneously.  To clarify the situation, suppose that you throw a single 6-sided fair die, and you are focusing on the following mutually exclusive events:

- the die comes up a 1 : probability $= (1/6)$.
- the die comes up a 2 : probability $= (1/6)$.
- the die comes up some other number : probability $= (2/3)$

The 3 events above are mutually exclusive, and not independent events.  Never the less, the $(1/6), (1/6), (2/3)$ probabilities stand.

With respect to dropping the pouch, the analogy is apt:

- the event of dropping the pouch when going from A to B : probability $= 0.1$.
- the event of dropping the pouch when going from B to A : probability $= 0.1$.
- the event of not dropping the pouch : probability $= 0.8$.

Comment: But ... if $p$ is the probability to drop the pouch on half-walk, won't we have the probability to drop it on the first part $p$ and on the second $(1-p)p$ so in total $20\%=2p-p^2$ i.e. $(1-p)^2=0.8$ i.e. $p=1-\sqrt{0.8}\approx 10.557\%$. Let's go the other way round: if the probability to drop it on the half-walk *was* $10\%$, then the probability that it is not dropped on the 1st half is $0.9$ and that it's not dropped on the 2nd half is $0.9$, so the probability that the pouch will not be dropped would be $81\%$, not $80\%$

Comment: @StinkingBishop No, this is wrong.  The two events are not independent.  Given that the probability is $10\%$ on each (1/2) of the route, you can infer that the probability of dropping it on the 2nd half (**given** that it was not dropped on the 1st half) is $(1/9)$, **not** (1/10).  Then, the probability of it not being dropped at all is $(9/10) \times (8/9) = 8/10$.  For clarity do **not** resist the die analogy.  If the die does not come up a (1), then the probability of the die coming up a (2) is (1/5), **not** (1/6).

Comment: @user2661923 why $\frac {1}{9}$?

Comment: But the events *aren't* symmetrical, because losing the wallet on the way back is inherently conditional on not having lost it on the way out there.

Comment: @CarlosLopez Assume the events of dropping it on the 1st (1/2), dropping it on the 2nd (1/2) and not dropping it are denoted as $E_1, E_2, E_3.$  Assume that $p(E_1) = (1/10) = p(E_2), p(E_3) = 8/10.$  Then, Bayes Theorem kicks in.  $$p(E_2 | \neg E_1) = \frac{p(E_2 ~~\text{and}~~ \neg E_1)}{p(\neg E_1)} = \frac{0.1}{0.9}.$$

Comment: @ConMan Unsure if you are directing the comment to me or not.  Also, unsure what you mean by the events are not symmetrical.  Unlike the die analogy, the events are not simultaneously trialed.  However, re my last comment, events $E_1, E_2,$ and $E_3$ are still mutually exclusive.  Are you disagreeing with my Math?

Comment: I agree that the events are mutually exclusive. I am disagreeing with your initial assumption that you should assign equal probability to events $E_1$ and $E_2$. I would argue that the events $E_1$ and $E_2| \lnot E_1$ are equivalent events, and hence should be equal probability, because they have the same conditions (they are the event of starting with a wallet, walking between A and B in some direction, and losing the wallet en route).

Comment: @ConMan Unsupported idea.  Consider: "In my daily morning walk there is a 20% chance".  Before the walk starts, is there any reason to regard the 2nd (1/2) of the walk as safer than the 1st (1/2).  The die rolling analogy is apt.  A more striking analogy is russian roulette, where a single bullet is placed in one of the 6 chambers, and you fire the gun twice, **not** spinning the chamber between shots.  Is the probability of being killed by the 2nd trigger-pull less than the probability of being killed by the 1st trigger-pull?

Comment: @user2661923 Sorry only now got round to replying to you. If the probability of losing the pouch on the first half was $10\%$, then the probability of losing it on the second half *given* that it is not lost on the first half will still be $10\%$. It is not $1/9$. You did try to argue using events $E_1, E_2, E_3$ but this is incorrect too. $p(E_3)=80\%$ and that is all we know. If you assume $p(E_1)=10\%$ then obviously $p(E_2)=10\%$ - but this is a circular argument which cannot be used to prove that $p(E_1)=10\%$.

Comment: Russian roulettes aside, the best analogy for me is radioactive decay here. You have an isotope which will decay to $25\%$ of the original amount in $2$ hours. Obviously, its half-period is one hour. However, in the first hour we will have $50\%$ of the nuclei decay, and in the second period we will have only $50\%$ of the remaining $50\%$, i.e. only $25\%$ of the nuclei decay. So twice as many nuclei decay in the first hour than in the second hour.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I think that we should agree to disagree.

Comment: @user2661923 I disagree to agree to disagree, but it would be interesting to see more opinions from the community. It may be down to different interpretations of the problem. I would be curious which interpretation leads to your solution.

Comment: @user2661923 I disagree with your answer. To explain this is a bit too much for a comment, so instead I edited my own answer to make clear why. So if you are interested then please take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I support @ConMan’s answer. Simply put, assume probability of dropping pouch is $p$ and hence not dropping it is $q = (1-p) $. So, total probability of losing it is
$$ P(E) = p*1 + (1-p)*p = 0.2 $$

On solving the quadratic, $ p = 1 - 2/ \sqrt 5 = 0.1056 (approx) $.
Also, the probability of losing the pouch is $higher$ in the first half AB, as $p > p(1-p) $, since $ 0<p<1 $ and this is actually intuitive.

This is because when you drop it in the first half, the second path outcome is irrelevant, so it’s basically that your do not drop your pouch with probability of 1.

On the other hand to drop it in the second half, you should not drop it in the first half, hence a condition comes into play and reduces your probability.

( From $p$ to $p(1-p)$ ). So answer = $0.1056$.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the conflicting answers: The question mentions that OP perform their "daily morning walk" "every day". Assuming that once the pouch is dropped it is not recovered for subsequent walks (the same assumption that OP used in their question).

From [other answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4444282/89922), given that OP starts a daily walk with the pouch,

- they might drop the pouch in one round trip with probability $20\%$;
- they might drop the pouch in one trip from A to B with probability $p \approx 10.557\%$;
- they might drop the pouch in one trip from B to A with probability $1-p \approx 9.443\%$;

but these probabilities are only correct for the first day, and do not consider the "daily" aspect.

The actual "probability I dropped it from A to B" is

$$p + (1-20\%) p + (1-20\%)^2 p + \cdots = \frac{p}{20\%} \approx 52.786\%$$

The corresponding probability that OP dropped it from B to A is

$$(1-p) + (1-20\%) (1-p) + (1-20\%)^2 (1-p) + \cdots = \frac{1-p}{20\%} \approx 47.214\%$$

Answer (score 0):

To add to the conflict answers: Why assume that OP does not pick up a dropped pouch? After all, if OP does not pick up the pouch, how would they repeat the same morning walk "every day"?

What if OP knows how to pick up the pouch immediately when dropped, and might drop the pouch in each part of the walk independently with probability $p$?

$$\begin{align*}
1-(1-p)^2 &= 20\%\\
p&= 1-\frac{2}{\sqrt5} \approx 10.557\%
\end{align*}$$

It's the same answer that OP might drop the pouch from A to B with probability $10.557\%$.

What's different here is that OP also might drop the pouch during the return part with the same probability $10.557\%$.

Comment: He says the probability on the return trip is conditional on what happened on the first half of the trip: if he already dropped the pouch then the probability of dropping it on the return trip is zero.

Comment: @DavidK OP also said "there is equal probability for me to drop my pouch in any of the two directions" and considered "Independent events or conditional probability?" So I am exploring other assumptions and add to the confusion.

Comment: It's true that OP is confused about how to define and compute probabilities in the scenario they have set up. I was merely seizing on one of the statements they made that was not really a statement of probability and seemed least likely to have been corrupted by a mistaken intuition.

Answer (score -1):

All of these comments that mention "intuitively" seem to be from a non-intuitive (calculating) perspective. The intuitive view for many people, IMO, is that the risk is the same on both parts of the journey, and therefore the probability is divided equally. Granted, naive intuition is often wrong, e.g. Monty Hall responses. But, because we have a mathematical tool, it doesn't mean we should always use it. The issue here is that "one event is dependent", so it seems that we MUST use the conditional probability formula from Bayes. The problem with that is: it ends up distorting the reality that every step, in either direction, is memoryless and contains the same amount of risk (of dropping the pouch). I don't believe those who are saying the probability is higher on the first part of the journey. If you follow that logic, every single step becomes less risky (with no reason to think that). The "independent event" is just part of a continuous, uniform probability distribution, and exactly half of that.

Comment: Actually it is precisely the "memoryless" property of the risk that says the probability is not "divided equally." Each time you start out with a pouch in either direction between A and B, you have a $10.56\%$ chance of dropping the pouch before you get to the other end of that journey. But you only have an $81.44\%$ chance of having a pouch when you start the portion of the trip from B to A.

Comment: I assume you mean 89.44%. I could be wrong in that there is a uniform distribution. It would be more convincing if the distribution were described as something else, such as Erlang or power-law. No one has addressed that. Also interesting, how things change when dividing the trip into smaller segments. I wonder if the first tenth of the trip has much higher probability than the last tenth. I guess the one-time nature of dropping something (we are to believe) is different than other events that can repeat. There should be more to it than non-repeating, though.

Comment: Yes, $89.44\%$. The exponential distribution has been mentioned.

Comment: After looking into failure analysis, I see how this could be described as a one-time, failure event, and modeled by an exponential distribution (without more information). We can have a "constant failure rate", and also an exponential probability distribution. That may be the "uniform" aspect I was considering.